# Is planarity really necessary for conjugation?

Tags: hybridization, resonance

If we look at the $\ce{ClO4-}$ anion, the chlorine atom in it is sp<sup>3</sup> hybridised. Hence, it has a tetrahedral structure in which conjugation shouldn't be possible, but while explaining the acidic strength of $\ce{HClO4}$, I've seen many people claim that it is very acidic because the $\ce{ClO4-}$ anion is stable due to the conjugation of charge between the four oxygen atoms.

So, all of this boils down to: Is planarity really necessary for conjugation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74958/discussion-on-question-by-user26732-is-planarity-really-necessary-for-conjugatio).

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48113/why-is-hclo4-the-strongest-oxyacid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a rather good question several students have actually asked me about it. it is not any exeption or contradiction .i have written the explanation below
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you type your answer out please? The content seems to be very nice. Thanks

Comment: I can't read that, please type it out. I would then even consider removing my down-vote.